# raster_value returns lat/lon instead on X/Y

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, coordinates, georeferencing

I have a project where the CRS is ESRI:102748.

When I use the Value Tool to hover the mouse over the raster, it returns the coordinates as X,Y,Z in feet.

I have a SpatiaLite point layer where I insert points. When I open the field calculator for the SpatiaLite point layer attribute table and add attempt to add a new field, MaxEl  (decimal) using the expression:

```
raster_value('demRasterLayer', 1, $geometry)
```

it always returns null.

It seems the reason is because $geometry is returning lat/lon.

I confirm this because creating a new field name X with the Expression $x returns a longitude.

Doesn't assign the CRS to the raster layer georeference it?

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, what CRS is the point layer in? Is it the same as the raster layer?

Comment: same ESRI:102748

Comment: I just noticed that if I create a shapefile layer, it works correctly.  It must be something in the spatialite.  In creating the spatialite layer I choose a geometry type of Point and leave the CRS as epsg:4326 - WGS 84.  Then in layers I change the CRS to 102748.